# js get the index number for key of an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The object

```
{
"Home work": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "student_id": 2,
        "activity_id": 3,
        "checked": 1,
        "checked_at": "2023-02-07 06:03:06",
        "completed": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-06T12:31:22.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-07T06:03:11.000000Z",
        "activity_category_name": "Home work"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "student_id": 2,
        "activity_id": 2,
        "checked": 1,
        "checked_at": "2023-02-07 06:03:38",
        "completed": 0,
        "created_at": "2023-02-06T10:44:31.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-07T06:03:38.000000Z",
        "activity_category_name": "Home work"
    }
],
"Daily activity": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "student_id": 2,
        "activity_id": 1,
        "checked": 1,
        "checked_at": "2023-02-05 11:18:56",
        "completed": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-05T10:40:25.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-05T11:18:56.000000Z",
        "activity_category_name": "Daily activity"
    }
]}
```

Here i want the index number of `Home work` which will be 0.

I tries

```
for((val, index) in array)
{
   console.log(val) // output 'Home work : [...]'
   console.log(index) // output 'Home work'
}
```

I need to find the index number here

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```js
    var json = {
      "Home work": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "student_id": 2,
          "activity_id": 3,
          "checked": 1,
          "checked_at": "2023-02-07 06:03:06",
          "completed": 1,
          "created_at": "2023-02-06T12:31:22.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2023-02-07T06:03:11.000000Z",
          "activity_category_name": "Home work"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "student_id": 2,
          "activity_id": 2,
          "checked": 1,
          "checked_at": "2023-02-07 06:03:38",
          "completed": 0,
          "created_at": "2023-02-06T10:44:31.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2023-02-07T06:03:38.000000Z",
          "activity_category_name": "Home work"
        }
      ],
      "Daily activity": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "student_id": 2,
          "activity_id": 1,
          "checked": 1,
          "checked_at": "2023-02-05 11:18:56",
          "completed": 1,
          "created_at": "2023-02-05T10:40:25.000000Z",
          "updated_at": "2023-02-05T11:18:56.000000Z",
          "activity_category_name": "Daily activity"
        }
      ]
    };


    var keys = Object.keys(json);
    for (const key of keys) {

      console.log(key);
      var result = keys.indexOf(key);
      console.log(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is an Object, We cannot access its key "Home Work" as index 0 but you can try Object.keys(yourObject) to access all of its keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index numbers of keys of an object just by using the `Object.keys()` method, which returns a list of all the keys of the object. Then,  you use `forEach` method to iterate over the list of keys and get the index of each key.

**Example:**

```
var yourObject = {
"Home work": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "student_id": 2,
        "activity_id": 3,
        "checked": 1,
        "checked_at": "2023-02-07 06:03:06",
        "completed": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-06T12:31:22.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-07T06:03:11.000000Z",
        "activity_category_name": "Home work"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "student_id": 2,
        "activity_id": 2,
        "checked": 1,
        "checked_at": "2023-02-07 06:03:38",
        "completed": 0,
        "created_at": "2023-02-06T10:44:31.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-07T06:03:38.000000Z",
        "activity_category_name": "Home work"
    }
],
"Daily activity": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "student_id": 2,
        "activity_id": 1,
        "checked": 1,
        "checked_at": "2023-02-05 11:18:56",
        "completed": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-05T10:40:25.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-05T11:18:56.000000Z",
        "activity_category_name": "Daily activity"
    }
]}
```

To get both keys and their index, use:

```
Object.keys(yourObject ).forEach((key, index) => {
    console.log(`Key:: ${key}, index:: ${index}`)
})
```

If you want to get only the indexes of the keys, use:

```
Object.keys(yourObject ).forEach((key, index) => {
    console.log(index)
})
```